# How to make histogram of NIR band bimodal enough to differentiate water from land in GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, band, histogram, water

I am interested to map water bodies in a desert from swir band of sentinel 2.

How I can make a bimodal histogram in GEE?

I have one reference water body in scene.

Is it possible to do the same in imagej?

Answer (score 1):

You can create the histogram using `ui.Chart.image.histogram`:

```
var image = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20210602T082601_20210602T083920_T35QRF')    
Map.addLayer(image, {bands: 'B4,B3,B2', max: 5000}, 'rgb')
Map.addLayer(image, {bands: 'B8', max: 5000}, 'nir')
var chart = ui.Chart.image.histogram({
  image: image.select('B8'), 
  scale: 1000
})
print(chart)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/f3816c99d56a2e66f204ba2c50eae657